# Why is this Haskell expression so slow?

Tags: haskell, optimization

I'm working on Project Euler Problem 14. Here's my solution.

```
import Data.List

collatzLength :: Int->Int
collatzLength 1 = 1
collatzLength n | odd n = 1 + collatzLength (3 * n + 1)
                | even n = 1 + collatzLength (n `quot` 2)

maxTuple :: (Int, Int)->(Int, Int)->Ordering
maxTuple (x1, x2) (y1, y2)  | x1 > y1 = GT
                | x1 < y1 = LT
                | otherwise = EQ
```

I'm running the following out of GHCi

```
maximumBy maxTuple [(collatzLength x, x) | x <- [1..1000000]]
```

I know that if Haskell evaluated strictly, the time on this would be something like O(n<sup>3</sup>). Since Haskell evaluates lazily though, it seems like this should be some constant multiple of n.  This has been running for nearly an hour now. Seems very unreasonable.  Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: I don't see why Haskell's laziness should make any difference to the complexity of this algorithm.

Comment: Your function `collatzLength` is not tail-recursive. This slows down the function and causes unneeded allocation. And your `maxTuple` is the same as `comparing fst`.

Comment: @sepp I don't really know how List Comprehensions are implemented. If they're using Map, if Haskell evaluated strictly, it seems like it would have to pass through the list multiple times.

Comment: @Josh That could indeed be a reason. IIRC this was an issue in other programs too, although I can't recall where.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really think too hard about the evaluation. I rewrote collatzLength to be tail recursive and it's still slow. Also, I didn't compile this. It didn't seem like I should have to.

Comment: @Josh: Post your update as a new question. It's a linking problem that's not really related to the topic here.

Comment: Hammar, I've removed the edit. The new post is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140617/ghc-linking-problem

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're assuming that the `collatzLength` function will be memoized. Haskell does not do automatic memoization. You'll need to do that yourself. Here's an example using the [data-memocombinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-memocombinators) package.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord
import qualified Data.MemoCombinators as Memo

collatzLength :: Integer -> Integer
collatzLength = Memo.arrayRange (1,1000000) collatzLength'
  where
    collatzLength' 1 = 1
    collatzLength' n | odd n  = 1 + collatzLength (3 * n + 1)
                     | even n = 1 + collatzLength (n `quot` 2)

main = print $ foldl1' max $ [(collatzLength n, n) | n <- [1..1000000]]
```

This runs in about 1 second when compiled with `-O2`.

Answer (score 1):

For being able to find a maximum of a list, the whole list needs to be evaluated.

So it will calculate `collatzLength` from `1` to `1000000` and `collatzLength` is recursive. The worst thing is, that your definition of `collatzLength` is even not tail-recursive.

Comment: This answer misses the point. The entire list *does* need to be evaluated, but by recording (memoizing) the results of `collatzLength`, it can be greatly sped up precisely *because* it is recursively defined. I think that's the nugget of wisdom that this Euler problem is supposed to convey.

Comment: okay, but he asked about lazy evaluation. And I told that lazy evaluation will not make it faster here because everything needs to be evaluated (at least once) anyway. But you're right! The problem is not evaluating everything once, the problem is evaluation everything _more_ than once.

Comment: Ah, I see where you were coming from now. You, too, are correct: the whole list needs to be evaluated, therefore laziness won't really help; the poster's confusion apparently came from not clearly understanding lazy evaluation, assuming it included memoization magic which it does not.

Comment: yeah, that's it, I think :-). He perhaps mixed up purity and laziness? Pure functions COULD have auto-memoization...

Answer (score 0):

`cL` is short for `collatzLength`

`cL!!n` stands for `collatzLength n`

```
cL :: [Int]
cL = 1 : 1 : [ 1 + (if odd n then cL!!(3*n+1) else cL!!(n `div` 2)) | n <- [2..]]
```

Simple test:

```
ghci> cL !! 13
10
```

Comment: Basically, this uses a list that memoizes `collatzLength` as it constructs itself. But it's rather mind-boggling when you try to trace the order of execution for `cL !! 3`, which depends on `cL !! 10`, a later element in the list which will get evaluated earlier!

Comment: @Dan Burton, the worst is that it runs slowly, maybe cause by (!!).

Comment: Yes, `!!` adds a portion of *O(n)* time complexity into the heart of the algorithm (in contrast, a memoized function should be *O(1)* to invoke or *O(log n)* at worst for the lookup), so for large `n` you will definitely see a big slowdown.