# GHC linking problem

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, ghc

I'm trying to compile the following code.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord
import qualified Data.MemoCombinators as Memo

collatzLength :: Int -> Int
collatzLength = Memo.arrayRange (1, 1000000) collatzLength'
  where
    collatzLength' 1 = 1
    collatzLength' n | odd n  = 1 + collatzLength (3 * n + 1)
                     | even n = 1 + collatzLength (n `quot` 2)

main = print $ maximumBy (comparing fst) $ [(collatzLength n, n) | n <- [1..1000000]]
```

The Haskell compiler spits out:

```
euler14.o: In function `s1pw_info':
(.text+0x8dd): undefined reference to `__stginit_datazmmemocombinatorszm0zi4zi1_DataziMemoCombinators_'
euler14.o: In function `rfX_info':
(.text+0x35d): undefined reference to `datazmmemocombinatorszm0zi4zi1_DataziMemoCombinators_arrayRange_info'
euler14.o: In function `rfX_srt':
(.data+0x4c): undefined reference to `datazmmemocombinatorszm0zi4zi1_DataziMemoCombinators_arrayRange_closure'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried googling, but to no avail. Is there anywhere these errors can be looked up? What do they mean?

Comment: Those identifiers make my eyes hurt. Is there C++ involved somewhere down there?

Comment: What does your GHC command line look like? Have you tried `ghc --make Foo.hs`?

Comment: I just typed in ghc -O2 euler.hs. Apparently it needed to be ghc-O2 --make euler14.hs

Comment: @Donal: GHC mangles symbol names similarly to what C++ compilers do. The package those symbols belong to ([data-memocombinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-memocombinators)) is pure Haskell.

Comment: @hammar: Phew! It just brought back really bad memories…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gotta compile with the [--make](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/5.00/set/make-mode.html) flag.